# client parameters in GWT RequestFactory

Tags: gwt, parameters, requestfactory

I´m using GWT RequestFactory and want to transport client-side parameters in a service.
The parameters should be created on the client, because they aren´t part of the domain model and won´t be stored in the database.
Unfortunately I found no way to do this, because only xxxProxy objects can be used as parameters and they can only be created on the server.

My concrete example:

I want to download tasks from a server and want to send a filter object with the request as parameter, which specifies the task objects to be loaded.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Stefan. Please mark Thomas' answer as correct, if it solved your problem. Feedback keeps stackoverflows' wheels turning.

Answer (score 3):

You can very-well create proxies on the client, using the `create()` method of your `RequestContext`. In your case, your proxy would have to be `ValueProxy` rather than an `EntityProxy`. You don't have to "store" value proxies (contrary to entity proxies).

I do have the exact same use case as yours, and it works very well.

```
@Service(MyService.class)
interface MyRequestContext extends RequestContext {
   Request<List<TaskProxy>> findTasks(FilterProxy filter);
}

@ProxyFor(Filter.class)
interface FilterProxy extends ValueProxy {
   // your getters and setters here
}
```

...

```
MyRequestContext ctx = ...;
FilterProxy filter = ctx.create(FilterProxy.class);
filter.setXxx(...);
// set your other filter
ctx.findTasks(filter).fire(new Receiver<List<TaskProxy>>() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(List<TaskProxy> tasks) {
     // ...
   }
});
```

As a side note, you wrote “only xxxProxy objects can be used as parameters”, which is wrong; you can very well use primitive types (`int`, `boolean`, etc.), their wrapper types (`Integer`, `Boolean`, etc.), `String`, `Date`, and `List` or `Set` of them (or proxy types).